# How to make an arraylist constant for multiple runs of a single class?

Tags: java

I am writing a simple server client application where the server class runs single time and the client runs multiple times.

As the clients keep coming and for each clients, I assign a name and send it to the server. There is also a client handler class for handling them.

But the issue is I am trying to save the password and username of a client to an `arraylist` and every time I run the Client class it creates new object of that `arraylist` and for each run, two of the logins are not saved in the same `arraylist` .I know I can implement login system by implementing database or saving those strings into a file but my question is, how can I save multiple class run information into a single `arraylist` ?

Comment: Can you share your attempt of where it fails?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/uPF1MhRU it's not fully done yet i dont want to overwrite the two arraylist everytime i run the code

Comment: You could maybe make the `ClientHandler` singelton? That way it is always the same instance that answers your client requests

Comment: Clienthandler is basically a thread class so I can't do it there , I have to authenticate the user from the start , from the client class , that is why I am having this problem and sorry i have no idea about singelton

Comment: Well, are you *literally* starting multiple programm-instances of your client class? Or just in one programm creating multiple Clients

Comment: Because `static` is only available in one programm-instance and when you have multiple of them, it is reset every time

Comment: here one program creating multiple classes

Comment: @Lino how to stop that reset ?

Comment: You can't really do that without using the filesystem. But why are you needing those passwords saved in the first place?

Comment: time to use file then , thank u very much . This is just a lab task my teacher gave me , he just went on and said "GO and make a login system without using file and bla bla " that's why

Answer (score 1):

Every time you start a new instance of the application running your client class, new lists are created for that instance. If you want to keep all the information in main memory, you need a *ClientHandler*-Program running **only once** that keeps track of your client credentials.